# How to extract ZIP files with WinRAR command line?

Tags: command-line, rar, unrar, winrar

While trying to extract zip files I get the error:

> c:\path\name.zip is not RAR archive
>   No files to extract

My code is:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x -o- {2} \"{0}\" * \"{1}\"\\ ",
  szFN,
  outFolder,
  passWord == null ? "" : string.Format("-p\"{0}\"", passWord));
```

The GUI version can extract zip and 7z files.

Why doesn't this work? How can I extract zip and 7z files?

(NOTE: I have different source code for 7zip. I guess I can merge the two and only use the above when the file has a rar extension. But I don't like that solution.)

Comment: try using the UnRAR.dll COM library instead

Comment: This is an old thread but I got here asking the same question. You can now use winrar.exe from the command line and it will work with zip files.

Answer (score 48):

Free `unrar.exe` and console version`Rar.exe` of *WinRAR* support only RAR archive format. That is clearly described in second paragraph in manual for `Rar.exe` which is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR*.

You need to use `WinRar.exe` instead which supports also other archive formats:

> [path\winrar.exe] x [switches] [path to zip file] [files to extract, *.* for all files] [path folder to extract to]

Example:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\winrar.exe" x -ibck c:\file.zip *.* c:\folder\
```

The syntax, commands and switches for GUI version `WinRAR.exe` are listed and described in help of *WinRAR*. Click in menu **Help** on menu item **Help topics**, open on help tab **Contents** the item **Command line mode** and read the help pages listed under this item.

For example the switch `-ibck` supported only by `WinRAR.exe` but not by `Rar.exe` is for running the extraction in background which means GUI version of *WinRAR* makes the extraction minimized to an icon in Windows system tray.

Comment: This works with both .zip and .rar archives. This is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

`rar.exe` can indeed only unpack rar files. It's not at all the same as WinRAR.

For unpacking ZIP files in .NET, you might want to look at the [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) library instead. It has a license compatible with commercial software, unlike CSharpZipLib.

If you need to support RAR as well, you can use UnRAR.dll with pinvoke:
http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm
http://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe

Or this .NET unRAR libary:
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rar-dotnet.asp

Perhaps [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx) for 7zip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`SevenZipSharp`](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) or [`DotNetZip`](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) Library in your Application!

But I will go for [`SevenZipSharp`](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) Lib as It supports all the archives supported by 7-Zip!

Both Source and Binary are available in the Links!

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to write a new program with libs. He wants to use a ready-built app to unzip an archive file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /on /b "D:\BACKUP_DATI\EXCEL\OPER*.ZIP"') do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x  "..\%G" –aoa
```

References to further reading:

- [7-Zip command line examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)
- [FOR /D - Loop through directory](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Comment: I think i end up using 7z but the question was for using winrar not 7z.