# Extracting .rar/.zip using c++

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, winrar

For no particular reason, I'm currently working on a program that extracts .zip/.rar files using `system()`.

I currently have WinRar installed because winrar.exe is able to handle both .zip & .rar files.

```
int main()
{
    vector<wstring> files;

    if (ListFiles(L"folder", L"*", files))
    {
        string program = "\"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\winrar.exe\"";
        string args = "x -y";
        string type = "*.*";

        TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH];
        GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, dir);
        wstring current_directory(wstring(L"\"") + dir + wstring(L"\\"));

        for (const auto& f : files)
        {
            if (wcscmp(PathFindExtension(f.c_str()), L".rar") == 0 ||
                wcscmp(PathFindExtension(f.c_str()), L".zip") == 0)
            {
                string file = ws2s(f.c_str());
                string output = "\"c:\\Users\\my name\\Desktop\\output\"";

                string command = program + " " + args + " " + ws2s(current_directory) + file + "\"" + " " + type + " " + output;
                cout << command << endl;

                if (system(command.c_str()) != 0)
                    return GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Because I'm using the command line, and don't want spaces to be a problem I wrap what I can in quotation marks:
     -- `"C:/users/username/program files (x86)/"` --
     -- `"folder/zipped folder.zip" vs folder/"zipped folder.zip"` --

After building the complete command contained in `command`, I printed it out to the screen so I could Edit->Mark:
`"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe" x -y "C:\Users\my name\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\extractor\folder\unzip.zip" *.* "c:\Users\my name\Desktop\output"`

However, `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` is what I'm met with after the `system(command)` call.

If I Copy & Paste the exact same command into Start->Command Prompt, it works like a dream.

[How to extract ZIP files with WinRAR command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315662/extracting-zip-with-winrar-command-line)
http://comptb.cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/
https://www.feralhosting.com/faq/view?question=36

Is there a way different way to invoke the `system()` call?
If there's not, how else can command line arguments be used?

I'd prefer to [avoid entirely] not use Boost:: or 3rd party libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably related to this [somewhat quirky behavior of Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/a/238813) (which indirectly affects `system`).  The solution would be to add an *extra* set of quotes around the *entire string* that's passed to `system`.

Comment: @Rufflewind That did it, actually. Interesting...I've never had that problem working with the command prompt before.

Comment: Not directly in Command Prompt.  You need to invoke `CMD` externally for the issue to become manifest (e.g. create a Shortcut that links to `cmd.exe /c <arguments>` and you'll see the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of the [quirky behavior of Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/a/238813) when it comes to quotation of arguments.  Whenever you call `system("\"arg1\" \"arg2\"")`, it is equivalent to calling:

```
cmd.exe /c "arg1" "arg2"
```

Because of the strange behavior as described in the linked post, this will not be interpreted correctly by Command Prompt.  An extra set of quotes is needed:

```
cmd.exe /c ""arg1" "arg2""
```

For invoking executables, [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) provides an alternative that gives you more control over the process.  You'll still have to quote the arguments but the [rules are a bit simpler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft.aspx) as the Command Prompt is no longer in your way.